# cant acces subdirectories Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I got magento on my own hosting and everything is running ok.
I created a landing (using HTML and CSS) and I wanted to include it inside my hosting.

I just created a folder inside root directory (where magento is loaded) and I uploaded my landing inside of that folder.

The problem comes when i try to access in that lading using my browser. I'm getting a 404 error by magento.

Can some one tell me if I am doing something wrong to be able to load that landing?

PS: I tried to delete cache, to reindex all files and still not working.